# How to slowdown capacitors discharge in simplest circuit

Tags: electrolytic-capacitor

I charge a capacitor rated 47uF @ 400 v in minute or so it charged up to 230 - 250 volts. However when connected to the a small motor it charges instantly and the motor spin in just brief moment. My question is how to discharge the capacitor smoothly so that it can run the motor at least for a minute or so...please advise..in simple circuit

Comment: I would suggest you is to stop your experiments. Your question is demonstrating the level of understanding which is making it very dangerous to play with such a voltages.

Comment: and in short you can't

Comment: I already expected such advise but don't worry --- i have done this a many times and i am completely aware of the danger. I just don't understand how to slowly discharge the capacitor thats all i need the answer

Comment: @rookie_coder You *do not understand the meaning* of what you are asking. The straight-forward answer will be  - add a resistance in series. But it is not what you want for sure.

Comment: At least this give me an idea what to look for...i will learn and experiment it...

Comment: What is your goal?  Are you trying to learn about how capacitors work?  In that case, you either need a much bigger capacitor (supercap), followed by a switching regulator...or, you need to use the capacitor to driver something with much lower current (perhaps an LED, but be careful to choose the right value of series resistor).  If learning is not your purpose, what is?

Comment: To learn and experiment the behavior i have a circuit that step up 3 volt to 500 volt...to charge capacitor and it does it fast...but now i want that capacitor to run just a small DC motor like where it run on 3 volt DC...i want to see how long is the capacitor discharge its charge to run the motor

Comment: @rookie_coder this is not the best place to learn electronics, as you need to have a background in electrical engineering to post good questions. For help on appropriate topics see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic This site is a Q&A site specifically for electrical engineers and those who have a background in it. To answer your question see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capchg.html#c1 and http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng.html#c1

Comment: Motor- capacitors are NOT used like batteries. They have much-much-more complicated functions (I also do-not know well). They are not also smoothing-capacitors. They have some role with AC-phase-curves.

Comment: You might searching a UPS or inverter or such.

Answer (score 4):

Your caps do not store enough energy to do anything but get yourself electrocuted. I guess you took them from a camera flash?

**EDIT**:
The energy stored in the cap can be computed as follows:
$$E=\frac{1}{2}CV^2 = 0.5 \times 47\cdot 10^{-6} \, F\times (400\,V)^2 = 3.8\,J$$
Painful if you were to touch it (it has over 200 volts behind it!). In that regard it's quite a lot of energy.

Ignoring the fact that the voltage is so absurdly high, that amount of energy will just not power any motor for a minute.

You could add a resistor in series with the motor, so to drop the voltage to a sane level and limit the current (thus increasing the discharge time), but then only a fraction of that energy gets delivered to the motor, rather than just dissipated in the resistor!

For comparison, a AA battery (let's say 1.5 V, 2.4Ah) stores as much as 13000 joules!

Comment: No...and your answer have no point...to me...not enough energy means what? please explain in numbers...this sound like a worthless place to ask question. i better run and bye bye

Comment: Updated my answer. Explicit enough now?

Comment: I liked your answers at least an idea what to look for and how to make it happen by the way 47  x 10 to the power of 6 is it converting the microfarad into farad?

Comment: @rookie_coder, yes, that's exactly what it stands for.

Comment: To repeat, this is just not going to happen *ever*. Let's suppose we bring down the voltage down from 200V to some sane 10V. Then you effectively loose 95% of the power in that resistance. There is no easy way around this. To power a motor you need a battery, or a low voltage, high capacity cap. Look for 'gold capacitors'.

Comment: And i thank for that for some valuable knowledge it gives me some clue why and what to search for

Answer (score 2):

I = C*dv/dt.  dv/dt is rate of change of voltage in volts per second.  Since your C is .000047, if your motor drew one amp continuous, your voltage would drop 1/.000047 or about 2130 volts per second.  You would be back to zero volts in about one-tenth of a second.

You can only discharge slowly by limiting current or adding capacitance.  @Eugene is right, charged capacitors can deliver high current at high voltage and is hazardous.